Cloud function emulator hangs when extracting json (Flask)
My cloud functions emulator hangs when making a request to login endpoint and just on Windows. This endpoint works perfectly fine on my linux laptop. The main problem is that in windows if i send the post request in the extraction of the json it hangs, because if i get rid of that extraction the login endpoint no longer hangs.
This is the endpoint done in python with flask:
import flask
import json
import requests
import os

# Get the current directory of the script
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Construct the path to keys.json
keys_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "..", "..", "keys.json")

with open(keys_path) as f:
    keys = json.load(f)

FIREBASE_API_KEY = keys['FIREBASE_API_KEY']

authBlueprint = flask.Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@authBlueprint.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    try:
        user = flask.request.json
        payload = json.dumps({"email":user['email'], "password":user['password'], "return_secure_token":True})
        rest_api_url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword"

        r = requests.post(rest_api_url,
                    params={"key": FIREBASE_API_KEY},
                    data=payload)

        response = r.json()
        token = response['idToken']
        return flask.jsonify({"message":"Login successful","token":token}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:",e)
        return flask.jsonify({"message":"Failed to login"}), 500

I already checked and the headers are correct, even in my main.py I establish correctly all the allowed headers for CORS and it works. As i already told you, this only happens on Windows, on Linux (Ubuntu) works like a charm.
